# gcloud app delpoy error response: [12] Connecting to an external network is not enabled for this project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a barebones app from a GCP tutorial that I would like to deploy to Google App Engine Standard. I am not connecting to anything externally, yet when I deploy via the SDK, I get the error response:

> (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [12] Connecting to an external network is not enabled for this project.

I would post code, but I have essentially copy/pasted the app engine standard for 
node.js tutorial at this point and still cannot get this to work.

app.yaml contents:

```
runtime: nodejs8
```

Error response screenshot: [gcloud error respone output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIW3R.png)

Comment: Hi matt, pls add printscreen or errors to precise your question.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You may want to provide the app.yaml you used. My guess is you tried to specify a network in a standard app which is not supported.

Comment: I just did [this quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) and deployed fine for me (the `app.yaml` is the same). Could you try following it?  Also, what quickstart did you follow? Did it work locally?